# 502 Bad Gateway while trying to use postgres ,flask with docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway
ProtocolException('Server connection to ('0.0.0.0', 8000) failed: Error connecting to "0.0.0.0": [Errno 61] Connection refused',)
while trying to test my docker image which is contain flask,postgres
Here is my code "app.py":

```
    import time
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


DBUSER = 'postgres'
DBPASS = 'postgres'
DBHOST = 'db'
DBPORT = '5432'
DBNAME = 'DB'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(
        user=DBUSER,
        passwd=DBPASS,
        host=DBHOST,
        port=DBPORT,
        db=DBNAME)
app.logger.info(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] )
#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
#app.secret_key = 'postgres'


db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    age = db.Column(db.integer))
    address = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age,address):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address


def database_initialization_sequence():
    db.create_all()
    test_rec = users(
            'John',
            'doe',
            20,
            '123 Foobar Ave ,los anglos')

    db.session.add(test_rec)
    db.session.rollback()
    db.session.commit()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['first_name'] or not request.form['last_name'] or not request.form['age'] or not request.form['address']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            user = users(
                    request.form['first_name'],
                    request.form['last_name'],
                      request.form['age'],
                    request.form['address'])

            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Record was succesfully added')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('show_all.html', users=users.query.all())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbstatus = False
    while dbstatus == False:
        try:
            db.create_all()
        except:
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            dbstatus = True
    database_initialization_sequence()
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0:8000')
```

also this my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.5-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Compose file

```
version: "3.3"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

requirements.txt

```
flask
flask-sqlalchemy
requests
redis
psycopg2
```

Comment: Your error silenced DB creation in a loop seems to ask for trouble.

Comment: actually I removed while loop ,but still the same error.

Comment: Can you connect to your just by using `server-ip:8000`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram I tried it with my serverip:8000 and with localhost:8000 both give the same result which is connection refused

Comment: @Soaad `docker ps`, what does it shows after you start the application.

Comment: just try adding `ports` to `db` service in docker-compose file. postgresql port `5432`

Comment: yes I updated yaml to have expose:  - 5432 and. build the image again,but still got same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230437/discussion-between-soaad-and-sachith-muhandiram).